# How to cast spring beans loaded in applicationContext to interface?

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I'm creating a Strategy Factory that loads through applicationContext all beans that have specific annotations. In my service, i would like to pass a string parameter to this factory and it should return me the correct implementation. But i'm faced with Cast Exception:

```
    @Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private Map<String,Object> strategyCache = new HashMap<>();


@PostConstruct
public void init(){

    Map<String, Object> annotatedBeanClasses = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(SimulationType.class);

    for(Object bean : annotatedBeanClasses.values()){

        SimulationType strategyAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(bean.getClass(), SimulationType.class);
        strategyCache.put(strategyAnnotation.platform(),bean.getClass());

    }
}


public SimulationStrategy getSimulationStrategy(String platform){
    SimulationStrategy strategy = (SimulationStrategy) strategyCache.get(platform);
    return strategy;
}
```

Im my service i would like to call this way:

```
SimulationStrategy strategy = simulationFactory.getSimulationStrategy(platform);
```

And this is my strategy class:

```
@Component
@SimulationType(platform="costumer")
public class ProductSimulation extends SimulationTemplate {
    Do Stuff....
}
```

Comment: `SimulationTemplate` vs `SimulationStrategy`?

Comment: @Sotirios, The SimulationTemplate implements the Interface used on Strategy...

Comment: So what `ClassCastException` are you getting? Post a full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the bean's `Class` in your `Map`, instead of the bean itself.

```
strategyCache.put(strategyAnnotation.platform(), bean.getClass());
```

should be

```
strategyCache.put(strategyAnnotation.platform(), bean);
```

Comment: Thanks Sotirios... i'm blind.. !